# Modify inputrc/set readline to allow down arrow to remove unfinished command from history

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, command-history, readline

On default Fedora and Debian and probably other distro installations one can type into bash and cycle previous history using up arrow and get back to the unfinished command using down arrow. Pressing down arrow on the unfinished command doesn't cycle to a blank slate as it seems the history buffer ends at the unfinished command. I want to make pressing down arrow cycle to blank slate but still allow pressing up arrow to go back to the unfinished command. Entering a new command when in the blank state would replace the previous unfinished command. Is readline capable of this and if so how can it be accomplished? Excuse me for asking beyond the scope of the main question but can zsh do this?